SAPUI5 UploadCollection, event beforeUploadStarts does not prevent incorrect files from being inserted
In my app I have a file uploader of the UploadCollection type, my problem is that when I upload the wrong file it enters the beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUpload" function, the error message appears correctly but the wrong file is added to the table anyway and I can't prevent it the insertion. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, online I've seen others do the same as me... So I have to prevent the insertion of a file that has formats other than those I specified


onBeforeUpload: function(oEvent) {
            debu**strong text**gger
            var aUploadedFiles = oEvent.getParameter("fileName");
            var aAllowedExtensions = ["pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "txt", "html"];
            var oUploadCollection = oEvent.getSource();

            if (!Array.isArray(aUploadedFiles)) {
                aUploadedFiles = [aUploadedFiles];
            }

            aUploadedFiles.forEach(function(sFileName) {
                var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

                if (!aAllowedExtensions.includes(sFileExtension)) {
                    MessageBox.error("Tipo di file non consentito. Si prega di caricare solo file con i tipi: PDF, DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, HTML, TXT");
                    oEvent.preventDefault();;
                    return 
                }
            });

            if (this._oDialog) {
                this._oDialog.setBusy(false);
            }
        },



